# I want to resize my linux root volume to create a separate partition. (aws ec2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, partitioning, xfs

//as-is

[root@ip-172-28-72-124 /]# lsblk

NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

nvme0n1       259:0    0  100G  0 disk

├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0  100G  0 part /

└─nvme0n1p128 259:2    0    1M  0 part

————————————————————————————————————

// to-be

[root@ip-172-28-72-124 /]# lsblk

NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

nvme0n1       259:0    0  100G  0 disk

├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   50G  0 part /

├─nvme0n1p2   259:1    0   50G  0 part /data

└─nvme0n1p128 259:2    0    1M  0 part

————————————————————————————————————

The file system is xfs.
How can I change nvme0n1p1 to 50G?

I tried to change the size using xfs_growfs but it failed.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. You even haven't provided OS which you are using.

Comment: I thought OS information was unnecessary for my question. It is amazon linux2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xfs_growfs is used for the opposite of what you want. If you are using a RHEL based system, [official answer](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-xfs) is you cannot.

"After an XFS file system is created, its size cannot be reduced. However, it can still be enlarged using the xfs_growfs command. For more information, see Section 3.4, “Increasing the Size of an XFS File System”)."

You may find some hacky ways of doing it but there is a risk element there.
I would recommend simply creating and attaching a 50Gig ebs volume if you simply need a second disk.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and accurate reply.